# SFDX Deploy: How to prevent accidental deploy to my Packaging Org

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, second-generation-packaging

From VSC, I'm deploying to my Dev Org often. I'm concerned that I may be authorized to my Packaging Org and accidently deploy code there.

In theory, the only deploys to Packaging Org should be from origin master from Repo. How can I prevent accidental deploys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no absolute foolproof way, but you can give yourself some assurances. First, set the Default Dev Org before you start working. You'll see which org you're connected to in the lower-left corner:

[image: Connected to sfdcfox Dev Org]

Almost all VSCode commands work on the default org, as well as commands in the terminal. The only exceptions are those that explicitly use a Dev Hub Org, such as Create A Scratch Org and Create a Package Version.

Second, consider using a Scratch Org, and use the push and pull commands. Push and pull will not work on Developer Edition orgs (only Scratch Orgs), so you'll minimize your chances of deploying to the wrong org by only using the push command for Scratch Orgs and Deploy for your Packaging Org.

Third, you may just also consider not using a Packaging Org at all. If you're still early in development, consider using a Second Generation Managed Package (2GMP). While there are still some limitations in the current version, using a 2GMP would minimize the risk significantly, since there is no org to upload from; you literally upload new versions from your repo metadata.